# How to check if my bot is in multiple guilds with the same name discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I want to make a leave command for my bot. This is my code so far.

```
  @commands.command()
  async def leave(self, ctx):
      """Remove me from the server. ;("""
      guild = discord.utils.get(client.guilds, name=ctx.guild.name) # Get the guild by name
      if guild is None:
          print("No guild with that name found.") # No guild found
          return
      await guild.leave() # Guild found
      await ctx.send(f"I left: {guild.name}!")
```

Yes, I its in cogs and the cogs work perfectly.
The problem - it uses guild names to remove the bot. Anyone can make a guild with the same name, use this command, and get my bot removed from the original guild.
I want my bot to check if there are multiple guilds with the same name, and if there are, it returns "Multiple guilds with the same name found! Please kick the bot manually."
If this is not possible, please suggest another solution.

Comment: Why not just do `ctx.guild.leave()`? It would automatically use the guild the command was in. Also, doing `await ctx.send()` after the bot left would not work, as the bot would no longer be in the guild and therefore it would raise an error. I recommend doing it before leaving.

Answer (score 3):

You can check if the bot is in multiple guilds with the same guild-name the command was executed in, with a simple count mechanism.

```py
guildsWithName = [guild.name for guild in client.guilds].count(ctx.guild.name)
```

Then check, if `guildsWithName > 1`:

```py
if guildsWithName > 1:
    print("Multiple guilds with same name found. Please remove manually.")
    return
```

However your code seem a little overcomplicated. What your `leave()` function does, is leave the guild the command was executed in, but will fail, if there are multiple guilds with the same name, as `discord.utils.get()` always returns

> the first element in the iterable that meets all the traits passed

Quote from the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#utility-functions).
You could just use `ctx.guild.leave()` instead.

---

However this is what you requested:

```py
  @commands.command()
  async def leave(self, ctx):
      """Remove me from the server. ;("""
      guildsWithName = [guild.name for guild in client.guilds].count(ctx.guild.name)
      if guildsWithName > 1:
          print("Multiple guilds with same name found. Please remove manually.")
          return
      guild = discord.utils.get(client.guilds, name=ctx.guild.name) # Get the guild by name
      if guild is None:
          print("No guild with that name found.") # No guild found
          return
      await guild.leave() # Guild found
      await ctx.send(f"I left: {guild.name}!")
```

---

Easier, more efficient and safer will be just using:

```py
  @commands.command()
  async def leave(self, ctx):
      """Remove me from the server. ;("""
      await ctx.guild.leave()
```

Maybe give it a try, and see if it fits your demands.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ctx.guild.id instead as all guilds have a unique id